# Android, Xamarin: Get mp3 from certain place on SD card and convert into URI to play

Tags: android, xamarin, media

I am currently working on a little app, that plays music. To test my app I want to play an mp3 that is stored on my sd card under:

```
SD-Card/Music/MYFILE.mp3
```

This needs to fit into here:

```
private void InitPlayer() {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(this, "URI TO MY FILE");
}
```

So I basically need to get the uri link to my file. I have not found a way to get to it. Can anybody help me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a post containing the following method on Xamarin Forums.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103478/how-to-get-path-to-external-sd-card

```
public static string GetBaseFolderPath( bool getSDPath = false )
{
   string baseFolderPath = "";

   try
   {
      Context context = Application.Context;
      Java.IO.File[] dirs = context.GetExternalFilesDirs( null );

      foreach ( Java.IO.File folder in dirs )
      {
        bool IsRemovable = Android.OS.Environment.InvokeIsExternalStorageRemovable( folder );
        bool IsEmulated = Android.OS.Environment.InvokeIsExternalStorageEmulated( folder );

        if ( getSDPath ? IsRemovable && !IsEmulated : !IsRemovable && IsEmulated )
            baseFolderPath = folder.Path;
      }
   }
   catch ( Exception ex )
   {
      Console.WriteLine( "GetBaseFolderPath caused the follwing exception: {0}", ex );
   }

   return baseFolderPath;
}
```

When the `basefolderPath` is obtained, you can get to your music folder and file by adding this to the address (the basefolderPath-string).

E.g.

```
baseFolderPath += "/YOUR_MUSIC_FOLDER/YOUR_MUSIC_FILE"
```

**ADDING TO YOUR SECOND QUESTION**

To get in the storage folder alone use the following method:

```
Android.OS.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Before using this method you may need to add the following permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thank you. This string returned: "/storage/05B6-2226/Android/data/Media_Player.Media_Player/files/

But this doesnt sound like the right folder at all^^. It should be somewhat: storage/emulated/0/music/xy.mp3.

Comment: 05B6-2226 is the ID of your external storage. If the device has a real external SD-card then you indeed are at the right location. Also check if your media player saves your music to the desired location.

Comment: Okay, so on my sd card, the folder is called "Music" and then there are many mp3 files in there.  Now, I just added "/Music/1.mp3" to the string and parsed it into an uri. But the mediaplayer.play method keeps crashing.

Comment: What does the debugger say? "can't find file"  or something else?

Comment: It isnt set to an instance of an object.

Comment: This sounds like somewhere you forgot to initiate an object, perhaps the `uri` or the `mediaplayer` object? Does your constructor have `mediaplyer = new mediaplayer()` for example?

Comment: No, I did that. But I found it out. So, the songs are all on my SD Card. But I was searching for my SD card via: Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryMusic)

This did return the INTERNAL STORAGE. But why would it do that? Since the folder was empty, I got nothing in return, so it didnt work. How can I use enviorment to find the SD card?? THank you!

Comment: I don't get it, the method above is not the one in my given answer. The one in my given answer did bring your to /storage/05B6-2226, are you sure your desired files are on your SD card? Also, check if permissions need to be set in order to access external storage.

Comment: Thank you, I mixed something up. you werer right :)

Comment: Thank you: May i bother you once more? So the basefolderpath returns: "/storage/05B6-2226/Android/data/Media_Player.Media_Player/files"

But I only need this adress until the "2226/" part. This is where all the folders are on my sd card. The rest of the adress goes to far then. I know I could hard code a cut of the long string, but this will only cause problems. How can I retrieve the string up until this part programtaically for everyone to be the same? The 2226 is some ID of my SD card, but this is different for each individual phone. Thanks once more

Comment: What is the name of your package? (Your project name). Does it happen to be named com.YOUR_NAME.Media_Player ?

Comment: "Media_Player.Media_Player" as stated in the long string!

Comment: Yeah I'd figured, no need for exclamation marks tryin' to help you out. I am not entirely sure how to get behind your path of origin but perhaps it is as simple as adding "../../"  before the rest of the baseFolderPath string so please try that first

Comment: Sorry, I was not intenting to be rude with the exclmation mark ;-). Well okay, what I did I am just going for .Remove(18). It is a bad way I know, but for every phone it SHOULD be storage/xxxx-xxxx/ so 18 digits. Ill look around further but for now itll do thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181288/discussion-between-mwbakker-and-innomotion-media).